# Alignment hoirzontal instead of vertical

Tags: python

I'm working on an assignment for school and we're supposed to make a script that counts to 100 in blocks of 10. So you would get number 1 to 10 in row 1, from left to right. In row 2 you'd get 10-20, from left to right, and so on.

I've wrote some part of the script but I can't figure out how to allign it from left to right, instead of top to bottom. This is what I've got so far:

```
def number(count):
 while count!=11:
    print(count)
    count=count+1;
number(0)
```

Comment: Please look at your question: it's missing code formatting. Please fix it, otherwise your python code (where whitespace matters) will be illegible. When [edit]ing your question, you can see the preview in the window. Please only submit the edit if what you see resembles your actual code.

Comment: Thanks, it's edited now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sys.stdout.write`, or `print()` specifying `end`

```
import sys

def number(count):
    while count!=11:
        sys.stdout.write('{0}\t'.format(count))
        #OR
        print(count,end=' ')

        count=count+1;
number(0)
```

Comment: If I'd go for the print version, how do I make it so it wouldn't paste all the numbers behind eachother? Now the output is 012345678910, but what if I want it to be like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10?

Comment: `end=' ',` not `end=''` (Note the space)

Comment: Thanks, that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

 numpy.arange(100)
 numpy.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
```

The above code should work fine.

Comment: Adding `numpy` as a dependency is probably not what OP's professor had in mind. Especially since this can be done without any imports.

Answer (score 0):

You could 'build-up' the string an then print the result. This may not be the best solution if you have a long string to print out, but for ten numbers at a time it would work.

For example:

```
some_string = ''
for i in range(1, 11):
    some_string += str(i)
print(some_string)
```

Following this idea, you could extend it to printing the rest of the numbers.

Just for kicks I'll also add that you COULD use list comprehensions in some way.

As an example:
`', '.join([str(x) for x in range(1, 11)])`